# How do you create multiple iOS apps from one Xcode Project?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I have a Sencha Touch 2 app wrapped in a native shell with PhoneGap. I have already created the native Android app. With my native Android app I have one Project and one apk for that Project. I have managed to create several apps from the one apk. I use the apktool to unpackage the apk then use some Perl script to update the index.html file with some global JS variables and I change the package name in the Smali files to make the app unique. Then I repackage the apk and sign it. The only difference between each app is the name and the url to send requests. This variables are set in the index.html. I would like to do the same for my iOS app. Is there a way to do this without creating multiple projects? Each app needs to be unique so I can have multiple instances on my device.

Comment: Why so -ve votes for this question? He is asking a very valid question!

Comment: I thought it was a very valid question. I don't use stackoverflow very often. I usually post on forums that are specific to the framework I am using. Maybe it is time to stop using stackoverflow.

Comment: Don't lose your heart because of 4 -ve votes! Stackovrflow is the best tech discussion forum right now... Some people are just eager to down vote.. I really don't understand what they r thinking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to do. Using your XCode project, create an ipa file. Now you can create mutiple copies of of your ipa file, change their bundle ids and resign them using a tool like [iResign](https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign) . Bundle Id identifies an app; so when bundle ids change and the app is resigned, you get a different app altogether!

Since now you have different bundle ids for apps in different environment, you need to use a plugin like [wizUtils plugin](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-plugin-wizUtils) and read the bundle identifier in your JS code and in a JS switch case statement, you can set dev and prod configurations(in your case service URLs) depending on the bundle id. So this way you don't have to change anything in the source code when you do the build for other environments.

Comment: Sounds similar to what I did with the Android apps. Thank you. I will give it a try.

Comment: Cool.. lemme know if you have more questions. If you found the answer as useful, please mark it as answer so that it helps the community.